# From array to mesh PLY file

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy array containing XYZ coordinates representing a point cloud. I would like to create a mesh ply file using [plyfile](https://pypi.org/project/plyfile/) in a list in order to create a PLY mesh file.

```
 vertex = [[52.45258174 78.63234647 -0.90487998]
           [52.46268174 78.68184647 1.09133402]
           [52.48928449 78.7930997 -0.90905187]
           [52.49938449 78.84259974 1.08716213]
           [52.5921233 78.92200466 -0.91276864]
           [52.6022233 78.97150466 1.08344536]]

PLY_vertices = PlyElement.describe(np.array(vertex, dtype=[('x', 'f4'), ('y', 'f4'),('z', 'f4')]), 'vertex')

ValueError: only one-dimensional arrays are supported
```

Comment: Just to be clear, numpy does not deal with tuples.  It's reasonable to want to combine those three arrays, but when you end up with is still an np.array.  And that's fine -- anything that expects a list of tuples should be able to read from such an array.

Comment: How will you write the file?  Does it actually have to be tuples?  How about a (6,3) fkiat stype arrat?

Comment: I don't see mention of 'tuple' in any ply doc.  And no [] or () in sample files

Comment: Have you tried just passing list containing your coordinates in a list containing actual tuples? I have not read the documentation at all but if it expects a 1d it might work like that.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
# If a zip object is okay
zip(arr1.flatten(), arr2.flatten(), arr3.flatten())

# If you want an ndarray
np.array(list(zip(arr1.flatten(), arr2.flatten(), arr3.flatten())))
```

It first flattens the arrays and then creates the required tuples.

However keep in mind that you should consider working with a 3xN or Nx3 coordinate array instead if performance is an issue.

something like:

```
# 3xN array
np.vstack((arr1.flatten(), arr2.flatten(), arr3.flatten()))

# Nx3 array
np.column_stack((arr1.flatten(), arr2.flatten(), arr3.flatten()))
```

Answer (score 2):

https://pypi.org/project/plyfile/

Shows some sample arrays

```
vertex = numpy.array([(0, 0, 0),
                     (0, 1, 1),
                     (1, 0, 1),
                     (1, 1, 0)],
                     dtype=[('x', 'f4'), ('y', 'f4'),
                        ('z', 'f4')])
face = numpy.array([([0, 1, 2], 255, 255, 255),
                  ([0, 2, 3], 255,   0,   0),
                  ([0, 1, 3],   0, 255,   0),
                  ([1, 2, 3],   0,   0, 255)],
               dtype=[('vertex_indices', 'i4', (3,)),
                       ('red', 'u1'), ('green', 'u1'),
                      ('blue', 'u1')])
```

Those might look like arrays of tuples, but those are actually `structured arrays`.  The dtype part is impotant.

We can get into construction methods, but first you need to provide the context.

### edit

To make a structured array, the data has to be list of tuples.

Your sample - a 2d array:

```
In [221]: vertex = np.array([[52.45258174, 78.63234647, -0.90487998],
     ...:            [52.46268174, 78.68184647, 1.09133402],
     ...:            [52.48928449, 78.7930997, -0.90905187],
     ...:            [52.49938449, 78.84259974, 1.08716213],
     ...:            [52.5921233, 78.92200466, -0.91276864],
     ...:            [52.6022233, 78.97150466, 1.08344536]])
     ...: 
     ...: dtype=[('x', 'f4'), ('y', 'f4'),('z', 'f4')]

In [222]: vertex
Out[222]: 
array([[52.45258174, 78.63234647, -0.90487998],
       [52.46268174, 78.68184647,  1.09133402],
       [52.48928449, 78.7930997 , -0.90905187],
       [52.49938449, 78.84259974,  1.08716213],
       [52.5921233 , 78.92200466, -0.91276864],
       [52.6022233 , 78.97150466,  1.08344536]])
```

convert it to a list of tuples:

```
In [223]: tups = [tuple(i) for i in vertex.tolist()]    
In [224]: tups
Out[224]: 
[(52.45258174, 78.63234647, -0.90487998),
 (52.46268174, 78.68184647, 1.09133402),
 (52.48928449, 78.7930997, -0.90905187),
 (52.49938449, 78.84259974, 1.08716213),
 (52.5921233, 78.92200466, -0.91276864),
 (52.6022233, 78.97150466, 1.08344536)]
```

Now make the structured array:

```
In [225]: M = np.array(tups, dtype)    
In [226]: M
Out[226]: 
array([(52.452583, 78.63235 , -0.90488   ),
       (52.46268 , 78.68185 ,  1.091334  ),
       (52.489285, 78.7931  , -0.9090519 ),
       (52.499386, 78.8426  ,  1.0871621 ),
       (52.592125, 78.922005, -0.91276866),
       (52.602222, 78.971504,  1.0834453 )],
      dtype=[('x', '<f4'), ('y', '<f4'), ('z', '<f4')])    
In [227]: M.shape, M.dtype
Out[227]: ((6,), dtype([('x', '<f4'), ('y', '<f4'), ('z', '<f4')]))
```

There is also a utility function that can do this:

```
In [232]: import numpy.lib.recfunctions as rf    
In [233]: M = rf.unstructured_to_structured(vertex, dtype)
```

### 2nd edit

Exploring the `face` structure:

```
In [236]: face = np.array([([0, 1, 2], 255, 255, 255),
     ...:                   ([0, 2, 3], 255,   0,   0),
     ...:                   ([0, 1, 3],   0, 255,   0),
     ...:                   ([1, 2, 3],   0,   0, 255)],
     ...:                dtype=[('vertex_indices', 'i4', (3,)),
     ...:                        ('red', 'u1'), ('green', 'u1'),
     ...:                       ('blue', 'u1')])

In [237]: face
Out[237]: 
array([([0, 1, 2], 255, 255, 255), ([0, 2, 3], 255,   0,   0),
       ([0, 1, 3],   0, 255,   0), ([1, 2, 3],   0,   0, 255)],
      dtype=[('vertex_indices', '<i4', (3,)), ('red', 'u1'), ('green', 'u1'), ('blue', 'u1')])
```

Because of (3,), the first field returns a 2d array:

```
In [238]: face['vertex_indices']
Out[238]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [0, 2, 3],
       [0, 1, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]])
```

The `rf` functions can handle this nested dtype:

```
In [239]: arr = rf.structured_to_unstructured(face)

In [240]: arr
Out[240]: 
array([[  0,   1,   2, 255, 255, 255],
       [  0,   2,   3, 255,   0,   0],
       [  0,   1,   3,   0, 255,   0],
       [  1,   2,   3,   0,   0, 255]])
```

So if you make a 2d array with enough columns, you can create as `face` style of structured array:

```
In [241]: rf.unstructured_to_structured(arr, face.dtype)
Out[241]: 
array([([0, 1, 2], 255, 255, 255), ([0, 2, 3], 255,   0,   0),
       ([0, 1, 3],   0, 255,   0), ([1, 2, 3],   0,   0, 255)],
      dtype=[('vertex_indices', '<i4', (3,)), ('red', 'u1'), ('green', 'u1'), ('blue', 'u1')])
```

Again, I'm just working from these few examples I pulled from the docs.  I haven't studied the ply format in any depth.

Sometimes it's easier to create a 'zeros' array with desired size and dtype, and fill in field values individually.  Many of the `rf` functions take this approach.  Usually an array has many more records than fields, so we don't loose much speed by iterating on fields.

```
In [242]: M =  np.zeros(3, dtype=face.dtype)
In [243]: M
Out[243]: 
array([([0, 0, 0], 0, 0, 0), ([0, 0, 0], 0, 0, 0), ([0, 0, 0], 0, 0, 0)],
      dtype=[('vertex_indices', '<i4', (3,)), ('red', 'u1'), ('green', 'u1'), ('blue', 'u1')])

In [244]: M['vertex_indices'] = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
In [245]: M
Out[245]: 
array([([0, 1, 2], 0, 0, 0), ([3, 4, 5], 0, 0, 0), ([6, 7, 8], 0, 0, 0)],
      dtype=[('vertex_indices', '<i4', (3,)), ('red', 'u1'), ('green', 'u1'), ('blue', 'u1')])
```

Comment: Thanks heaps @hpaulJ, and how do we create a face variable?

Comment: you mean one with a field like `('vertex_indices', 'i4', (3,)`?  The data has to have a list within the tuple. `([0, 2, 3], 255,   0,   0)`

Comment: yes, exactly. It looks like the code  that you proposed in response creates a point cloud instead of mesh. Thanks

Comment: I added a `face` structure example